# subschemes of abelian scheme over artinian basis

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $R$ be an artinian thickening of a field $k$. Denote with $S=Spec(R)$. Let $A$ be an abelian scheme over $S$. Let $X$ be a closed, reduced, equidimensional subscheme of the special fiber $A_k$. I would like to know if there is an Hilbert schemes parametrizing $R$-flat subschemes $\mathcal{X}$ of $A$ such that $\mathcal{X}_k\cong X$ and if any property of this object is known (dimension, connectedness,...). I am sure that some other invariants of $\mathcal{X}$ have to be fixed in order to get a nice object, but I do not know which ones.

Comment: Are you asking about $R$-flat closed subschemes of $A$ whose base change over $k$ equals $X$?

Comment: @JasonStarr yes.

Comment: Does the Artin ring $R$ contain $k$ as a coefficient field?  If so, then there is a Hilbert scheme parameterizing these subschemes, and it will be affine with a certain structure of iterated torsor for additive groups -- all this follows by infinitesimal deformation theory.  If $R$ does not contain $k$, you can still say something if the nilradical of $R$ is a square zero ideal.  However, beyond that, this is not really an object "over $k$".

Comment: @JasonStarr yes we can assume that $R$ contains $k$ as coefficient field. Do you know any reference for the construcion? Thanks